# Exibindo filtro apartir de outra view

Tags: cakephp, filtro

Tenho uma `View` onde é mostrado os dados do cliente, e ao clicar em um botão, o usuário é redirecionado para uma página que mostra as movimentações de diversos clientes, logo nessa página contém alguns filtros. Então o que eu preciso é que quando esse cliente clicar no botão e for redirecionado para a página com os filtros, que seja filtrado os itens referentes à ele.

### Por exemplo:

```html
<center><strong>--Simulando--</strong></center><br>
<i>Ao clicar no botão, da `View`, abrirá a página `Nfse`, pertencente à outra controller.</i>
<hr>
<br><br>
<strong><i>VIEW:</i></strong> <br><br>

<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Cliente</th>
    <th>Cnpj</th>
    <th>Nfes emitidas</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>XX SERVICOS</td>
    <td>00000000000100</td>
    <td><center><button>Nfes</button></center></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<i> Ao clicar no botão <button>Nfes</button> será redirecionado para ...</i>
<br><br>

<strong><i>Nfes:</i></strong><br><br>

<input type='text' placeholder='nr.nfe'>
<input type='text' placeholder='cnpj emitente' value='00000000000100'> <small><small>#Este campo deverá vir preenchido#</small></small>
<input type='text' placeholder='dt emissao'>
<input type='button' value='Filtrar'>

<br><br>
<i>Trazendo como resultado esses dados simulados!</i>
<br><br>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Nr.nfe</th>
    <th>cnpj emitente</th>
    <th>dt emissao</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11324</td>
    <td>00000000000100</td>
    <td>31/01/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11323</td>
    <td>00000000000100</td>
    <td>28/01/2017</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11322</td>
    <td>00000000000100</td>
    <td>15/01/2017</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Se tratando de duas `controller` diferentes, não estou conseguindo encontrar uma solução para isso, poderia colaborar com alguma ideia ou correção?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posso colabora com a seguinte ideia:

Na sua `View` substituir o elemento `<button>Nfes</button>` pelo Helper `FormHelper::postLink`. Que tem o seguinte formato:

> FormHelper::postLink(
>      string $title, 
>      mixed $url = null, 
>      array $options = array ()
>     );
>
> Cria um link HTML, mas acessa o URL usando o método POST. Requer que o JavaScript esteja ativado no navegador.
>
> Este método cria um elemento `<form>`. Se pretender utilizar este método dentro de um formulário existente, tem de utilizar as opções inline ou bloco para que o novo formulário pode ser processado fora do formulário existente.[[Book Cakephp, 2017](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postLink), p. 136].

```
<!-- File: /app/View/ControllerUm/sua-view.ctp -->
```

---

```
<td class="actions">
    <?php 
        echo $this->Form->postLink(
            __('Nfes'),
            //mixed $url = null 
            array(
                'controller' => 'ControllerDois',
                'action' => 'actionOfWork', 
                ['client_id' => $client['Client']['id']]
            ),
            //array $options = array ()
            array(
                'inline' => true,
                'class' => 'demo'
                //'confirm': "Sua mensagem de confirmação, vem aqui se necessário",
            )
        ); 
    ?>
</td>
```

---

O botão acima vai fazer um post passando o ID do cliente para URL especificada.

```
<!-- File: /app/Controller/ControllerUn/ControllerDois.php -->
```

---

```
 /**
 * A action no seu ControllerDois que vai receber o post.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function actionOfWork() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Client->id = $this->request->data['client_id'];
        if (!$this->Client->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Cliente inválido'));
        }

        /** 
         * Aqui você vai usar o seu algoritmo de trabalho da aplicação 
         */

        $dataClientFilter = $this->Client->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('dataClientFilter'));

        /** 
         * Em teoria o CakePHP vai mandar os dados filtrados para serem renderizados 
         * pela View: /app/View/ControllerDois/actionOfWork.ctp. 
         *
         */
    }
 }
```

---

Se entendi bem a sua pergunta acredito que seja isso!

---

**Referência**: 
<sub>[Book Cakephp, 2017], Disponível em: **[Book Cakephp - FormHelper::postLink](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postLink)**. Acesso: 05 Abr, 2017.</sub>

Comment: Perfeito !!
Exatamente isso que eu precisava, funciona perfeitamente, coloquei a `URL` que eu queria assim `mixed => $url`, passando a `controller` e a `action` de destino, muito bom !!

Comment: @MarcosHenzel, OK! Muito obrigado pela recompensa! Mas o mais importante é que foi útil para vc! A sensação é muito boa! Sucesso!

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que percebi, você não conhece os helpers. Eles facilitam a implementação do código, e faz tudo pra você, passando dados do php e montando a estrutura html com esses dados. Desculpe se interpretei errado.

Caso não tenha tentado, você pode fazer um link redirecionando para a view do outro controller, passando alguns parâmetros referentes ao cliente que deve ser filtrado.

```
$html->link(/* o botão */, 
    ['controller' => /* o controller */, 
    'view' => /* a view */, 
     $parametro1, 
     $parametro2]);
```

O controller e a view é pra onde quer redirecionar o cliente e se tiver mais parâmetros, é só colocar mais, separados por vírgulas. Lembrando que são os parâmetros que estão disponíveis na function do seu controller. Eu coloquei de forma genérica pois não sei exatamente como está sua estrutura Espero ter ajudado.